# Understand the result of sort on nested field in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am reading The ElasticSearch Definitive Guide,about sorting on  nested field in elastic search.

I am using Elastic Search 7.10.1

The following is the code that creates the index and prepares the data.

1. Create the index and setup the mapping

```
    PUT /my_index
    {
      "mappings": {
        "properties": {
          "body": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "comments": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "age": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "comment": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "date": {
                "type": "date"
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "stars": {
                "type": "long"
              }
            }
          },
          "tags": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

2. Insert the data:

```
PUT /my_index/_doc/1
{
  "title": "Nest eggs",
  "body": "Making your money work...",
  "tags": [
    "cash",
    "shares"
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "name": "John Smith",
      "comment": "Great article",
      "age": 28,
      "stars": 4,
      "date": "2014-09-01"
    },
    {
      "name": "Alice White",
      "comment": "More like this please",
      "age": 31,
      "stars": 5,
      "date": "2014-10-22"
    }
  ]
}

PUT /my_index/_doc/2
{
  "title": "Investment secrets",
  "body": "What they don't tell you ...",
  "tags": [
    "shares",
    "equities"
  ],
  "comments": [
    {
      "name": "Mary Brown",
      "comment": "Lies, lies, lies",
      "age": 42,
      "stars": 1,
      "date": "2014-10-18"
    },
    {
      "name": "John Smith",
      "comment": "You're making it up!",
      "age": 28,
      "stars": 2,
      "date": "2014-10-16"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. query and sort against the `comments.starts` field

```
GET /my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "comments",
      "query": {
        "range": {
          "comments.date": {
            "gte": "2014-10-01",
            "lt": "2014-11-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "comments.stars": {
      "order": "asc",
      "mode": "min",
      "nested_filter": {
        "range": {
          "comments.date": {
            "gte": "2014-10-01",
            "lt": "2014-11-01"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. The result is as follows:

```
{
  "took" : 0,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 2,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Nest eggs",
          "body" : "Making your money work...",
          "tags" : [
            "cash",
            "shares"
          ],
          "comments" : [
            {
              "name" : "John Smith",
              "comment" : "Great article",
              "age" : 28,
              "stars" : 4,
              "date" : "2014-09-01"
            },
            {
              "name" : "Alice White",
              "comment" : "More like this please",
              "age" : 31,
              "stars" : 5,
              "date" : "2014-10-22"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          9223372036854775807
        ]
      },
      {
        "_index" : "my_index",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "2",
        "_score" : null,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "Investment secrets",
          "body" : "What they don't tell you ...",
          "tags" : [
            "shares",
            "equities"
          ],
          "comments" : [
            {
              "name" : "Mary Brown",
              "comment" : "Lies, lies, lies",
              "age" : 42,
              "stars" : 1,
              "date" : "2014-10-18"
            },
            {
              "name" : "John Smith",
              "comment" : "You're making it up!",
              "age" : 28,
              "stars" : 2,
              "date" : "2014-10-16"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort" : [
          9223372036854775807
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I don't understand the result, I can't figure out how the `starts` is sorted. There is no difference if the have specied the `"order":"asc"` and `"order": "desc",`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your sort query as shown below. Refer to this official documentation, to know more about [nested sorting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.x/sort-search-results.html#_nested_sorting_examples).

**In the below sort query, first the documents are filtered on the basis of range query, then `comments.stars` value is sorted either in `asc` or `desc` order.**

The `mode` is used to decide what to do in case a field has multiple `comments.stars` values. For example in your case, in the given range, there are two documents under the `comments` having `stars` value `1` and `2`. When the mode is set to min, `stars` value `1` is considered.

```
     {
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "comments",
      "query": {
        "range": {
          "comments.date": {
            "gte": "2014-10-01",
            "lt": "2014-11-01"
          }
        }
      },
      "inner_hits": {}
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "comments.stars": {
        "order": "asc",
        "mode": "min",
        "nested": {
          "path": "comments",
          "filter": { // note this
            "range": {
              "comments.date": {
                "gte": "2014-10-01",
                "lt": "2014-11-01"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66254927",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "6ZHts3cBlRfCLR0mFU3F",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Investment secrets",
          "body": "What they don't tell you ...",
          "tags": [
            "shares",
            "equities"
          ],
          "comments": [
            {
              "name": "Mary Brown",
              "comment": "Lies, lies, lies",
              "age": 42,
              "stars": 1,
              "date": "2014-10-18"
            },
            {
              "name": "John Smith",
              "comment": "You're making it up!",
              "age": 28,
              "stars": 2,
              "date": "2014-10-16"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          1
        ],
        "inner_hits": {
          "comments": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 2,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "66254927",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "6ZHts3cBlRfCLR0mFU3F",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "comments",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "Mary Brown",
                    "comment": "Lies, lies, lies",
                    "age": 42,
                    "stars": 1,
                    "date": "2014-10-18"            // note this
                  }
                },
                {
                  "_index": "66254927",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "6ZHts3cBlRfCLR0mFU3F",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "comments",
                    "offset": 1
                  },
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "John Smith",
                    "comment": "You're making it up!",
                    "age": 28,
                    "stars": 2,
                    "date": "2014-10-16"               // note this
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66254927",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": null,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Nest eggs",
          "body": "Making your money work...",
          "tags": [
            "cash",
            "shares"
          ],
          "comments": [
            {
              "name": "John Smith",
              "comment": "Great article",
              "age": 28,
              "stars": 4,
              "date": "2014-09-01"
            },
            {
              "name": "Alice White",
              "comment": "More like this please",
              "age": 31,
              "stars": 5,
              "date": "2014-10-22"
            }
          ]
        },
        "sort": [
          5
        ],
        "inner_hits": {
          "comments": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 1.0,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "66254927",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "comments",
                    "offset": 1
                  },
                  "_score": 1.0,
                  "_source": {
                    "name": "Alice White",
                    "comment": "More like this please",
                    "age": 31,
                    "stars": 5,
                    "date": "2014-10-22"          // note this
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks @escoder. I modified the query and follow yours. there still a question for the query result. As you have pasted: why `` "date": "2014-09-01" `` also included in the comments? I have filter the comment to be in the range of 2014-10-01 ~ 2014-10-31

Comment: @Tom You can use `inner_hits` to get only those documents that are within the range. Please go through the updated query, and let me know if this resolves your issue?

Comment: Sure, thanks @escoder, understood, thanks!